# Error when trying to run job in Talend (run time error)

Tags: java, linux, talend

I'm using Talend 5.4.1 (from the VM).

I'm getting the following error when trying to run talend job (from each of the projects):

Error:

```
Could not find or load main class expenses_2.etladtech_0_1.ETLADTECH.
```

for more help i added the java version i'm using. (after observing the issue in other posts i saw that it's recommended to add it)

so I ran the command from the cmd of the VM:

```
[root@dev-talend1 ~]# java -version
```

Response:

`classpath=.;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\rt.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\dt.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\too ls.jar;
    java version "1.7.0_05"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b05)
    Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode, sharing)
    bash: fg: %JAVA_HOME%jrelibrt.jar: no such job
    bash: fg: %JAVA_HOME%libdt.jar: no such job
    bash: fg: %JAVA_HOME%libtools.jar: no such job
    You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
    [root@dev-talend1 ~]#`

what can i do to solve it?

Comment: You're missing a slash somewhere where `jrelibrt.jar`, `libdt.jar`, and `libtools.jar` are called.

Comment: How are you trying to execute? through a batch or sh script? If so, post that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Windows environment variables (`%JAVA_HOME%`) on a Unix machine. Use `$JAVA_HOME` instead. And don't run services as root.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick responses.
In the end i didn't find the cause for the error but after upgrading to a newer version of Talend 5.6.0 it was fixed.